# Serializers django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django rest framework, I am working on a small project and I am facing a truoble with serializsers what I need is one URL request with a list of all the name of school, and another URL request that has all the information about the school(name, city, street, student). The probleem is that in both URLs I get the same information which is (name, city, street, student). Can someone help me with that?

serializers.py

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     is_existing_student = = serializers.BooleanField()
     student = StudentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
      model = School
      fields = ['is_existing_student', 'name', 'city', 'street', 'student']



class SchoolNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model = School
    fields = ['name']
```

views.py

```
      class SchoolViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
      ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

         serializer_class = SchoolSerializer
         queryset = School.objects.all()


    class SchoolNameViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
     ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

         serializer_class = SchoolNameSerializer
         queryset = School.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
     router.register(r'schoolname', SchoolNameViewSet)
     router.register(r'school', SchoolViewSet)
```

Comment: This code looks correct. Can you confirm that you're hitting the `schoolname` url with your client / browser?

Comment: @schillingt - "schoolname": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/school/",
    "school": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/school/" after the api both urls hitting school

Comment: Where does `{"schoolname": "127.0.0.1:8000/api/school", "school": "127.0.0.1:8000/api/school"}` come from? There seems to be the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that information or what it means. If you install django-extensions, you can use `python manage.py show_urls` and it'll generate all the various urls that you have setup. From there you can see the URL you should be using for school name.